# Convert object to array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**ANGULAR**

```
<input class="" name="store_category[]" type="checkbox"  ng-model="store.store_category.A">A

<input name="store_category[]" type="checkbox" ng-model="store.store_category.B">B

<button type="submit" ng-click="addStore(store)"  class="btn btn-primary campwidth">SUBMIT</button>
```

when I console it. It shows object.

store_category

```
Object { A=true,  B=true}
```

A   true
B true

I want to send it an array. How to do this in angularjs.

Comment: Try using ng-true-value & ng-false-value attributes for a checkbox form control. Assign the object in ng-true-value. So when later you post your form the array would be array of objects.

Comment: won't iterating over object and pushing to new Array work according to the Data structure needed?

Comment: Note that using an array, you'll loose A and B keys because JS Arrays keys are integers unless you store them as individual objects in the array. Make an empty array. iterate over your store_category object and push to the empty array.

Comment: @Nivin Please find this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ql4e1PKhZvwSoCMgHDOH?p=preview